# Matching data onto Julian Calendar

Tags: r

I have a Julian calendar as below

```
 > head( Juldayts)
      Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
 1871  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
   tail(Juldayts)
    Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2012  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

and I have 28,000 time series example below, truncated at July for the purpose of space,put in fact full years

```
                         Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May    Jun    Jul        
                 1942   1.03   0.97  -0.47  -0.17  -0.90   1.00   0.01      
          tail(X2ts_stripped,n=12)
                       Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul     
                2009  0.35  0.75  0.35  0.72  1.94 -0.28  1.16
```

I want to map the the data onto the Julian calendar so I have a full calendar with NAs where the is no values and the appropriate values where there is.

I can't figure this one out, if anybody can help with a suitable piece of code

Comment: Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for a guide on creating reproducible examples. Especially some sample data using dput() would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you Florian. I will look at the information and guide. i am not sure I fully understand , that's my fault due to being still a novice on a very steep learning curve

Comment: Maybe this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386850/how-can-i-change-xts-to-data-frame-and-keep-index-in-r will be helpful. If you need more help, you should `dput` a small sample  of the dataset or analogous data.