# How to convert an xts to a data.frame that includes an index column?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts, quantmod

I pull stock information from quantmod and it returns a xts object, where the index is the date that each row's data corresponds to. How can I convert the index into a column? I attached a screenshot of the data frame's first 6 rows.

[image: index column has dates]

EDIT: Different than [How can I change XTS to data.frame and keep Index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386850/how-can-i-change-xts-to-data-frame-and-keep-index-in-r) because this question is from the prospective of a user who think the data is stored in a data.frame.  Potentially useful question for the uninformed or novice.

Comment: Data retrieved through `quantmod` is usually of class `xts`, which is not your normal dataframe.  Read up on `xts` objects in the `xts` package vignette, available [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xts/vignettes/xts.pdf).

Comment: @DanY Thank you so much. Your post lead me to this post that had the answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386850/how-can-i-change-xts-to-data-frame-and-keep-index-in-r

Comment: I just added [an answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52678996/271616) that will hopefully help new users.