# Convert xts/zoo object to data.frame in R

Tags: r, data-conversion

I have a data object called `NKLA` that looks like this:

```
> class(NKLA)
[1] "xts" "zoo"

> head(NKLA)
           NKLA.Open NKLA.High NKLA.Low NKLA.Close NKLA.Volume NKLA.Adjusted
2018-06-11      9.57      9.58     9.57       9.58      402600          9.58
2018-06-12      9.56      9.56     9.56       9.56      300000          9.56
2018-06-13      9.57      9.58     9.56       9.57      179100          9.57
2018-06-14      9.57      9.57     9.57       9.57           0          9.57
2018-06-15      9.57      9.57     9.57       9.57           0          9.57
2018-06-18      9.54      9.58     9.54       9.58         300          9.58
```

But when I try to convert it to data.frame like

- this as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387259/2950721): `data.frame(date=index(NKLA), coredata(NKLA))`
- or this, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28009224/2950721): `as.data.table(NKLA)`
- or this, suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10759011/2950721): `as.data.frame.matrix(NKLA)`
- but I also found this: `as.data.frame.table(NKLA)`
- and this: `as.data.table(NKLA)`
- and this too: `as.data.frame(NKLA)`

I each time get an `[1] "xts" "zoo"` to the query `class(NKLA)`.

My question:

- How do I convert an `xts`/`zoo` object into a `data.frame` object?

Any help appreciated.

---

System used:

- R version: 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
- RStudio version: 1.4.1717
- OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `fortify.zoo`

```
library(zoo)
df1 <- fortify.zoo(NKLA)
```

-output

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Index        : POSIXct, format: "2018-06-11" "2018-06-12" "2018-06-13" "2018-06-14" ...
 $ NKLA.Open    : num  9.57 9.56 9.57 9.57 9.57 9.54
 $ NKLA.High    : num  9.58 9.56 9.58 9.57 9.57 9.58
 $ NKLA.Low     : num  9.57 9.56 9.56 9.57 9.57 9.54
 $ NKLA.Close   : num  9.58 9.56 9.57 9.57 9.57 9.58
 $ NKLA.Volume  : num  402600 300000 179100 0 0 ...
 $ NKLA.Adjusted: num  9.58 9.56 9.57 9.57 9.57 9.58
```

#### data

```
NKLA <- structure(c(9.57, 9.56, 9.57, 9.57, 9.57, 9.54, 9.58, 9.56, 9.58, 
9.57, 9.57, 9.58, 9.57, 9.56, 9.56, 9.57, 9.57, 9.54, 9.58, 9.56, 
9.57, 9.57, 9.57, 9.58, 402600, 3e+05, 179100, 0, 0, 300, 9.58, 
9.56, 9.57, 9.57, 9.57, 9.58), .Dim = c(6L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("NKLA.Open", "NKLA.High", "NKLA.Low", "NKLA.Close", 
    "NKLA.Volume", "NKLA.Adjusted")), index = structure(c(1528689600, 
1528776000, 1528862400, 1528948800, 1529035200, 1529294400), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), class = c("xts", "zoo"))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, your solution does not seem to work. After trying ```fortify.zoo(NKLA)```,  ```class(NKLA)``` still renders ```[1] "xts" "zoo"``` and ```str(NKLA)``` renders ```An ‘xts’ object on 2018-06-11/2021-09-16 containing:```...

Comment: @pdeli If you see my solution.  it is is assigning to new object `df1` check the `str(df1)`  if you want to update the original object you need `NKLA <- fortify.zoo(NKLA)`

Comment: you are totally right! ```NKLA <- fortify.zoo(NKLA)``` works absolutely perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: @pdeli if it works, please consider to accept solution